# How to run update queries on spark-sql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am newbie in spark.Is there anyway that i could operate Update command in spark-SQL. I have already created a hive table where i have manipulated some SQL syntax queries like insert, select ,delete but could not able to run update  command. I have searched  on spark documentation  and https://docs.datastax.com/en/datastax_enterprise/4.6/datastax_enterprise/spark/sparkSqlSupportedSyntax.html site for this. but i did not find UPDATE Syntax in their recent list of Spark SQL. Kindly help me.I am using spark 2.0

Kalyan

Answer (score 2):

The general answer is that you can't. However, if the data is stored in Hive using ORC, you could do something like [this](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/exercises/spark-sql-hive-orc-example.html) to update the Table using Spark SQL.

Answer (score 2):

DataFrame records don't have any setter methods because DataFrames are based on RDD which are immutable collections, which means you cannot change their state. Thats is why spark sql does not support updates.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't do update queries, you'll have to work out how to do it as a `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

No you cant run update query in spark-hive, its not support transactional queries.

Answer (score 0):

HDFS is a write once file system and ORC is a write-once file format, so edits were implemented using base files and delta files where insert, update, and delete operations are recorded.